# Erro ao instalar .NET Core no Linux Mint

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, .net-core, mint

Ao tentar instalar o .NET Core no Linux Mint utilizando o Snap através do comando `sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic`, ao final da instalação do pacote, é exibido:

> "dotnet-sdk 3.1.401 from Microsoft .NET Core (dotnetcore✓) installed"

Ocorre, porém, que quando executo em seguida o comando `dotnet -v`, é exibido o seguinte:

> "**Command 'dotnet' not found**, but can be installed with: sudo snap install dotnet-sdk"

Tentei instalar usando o APT-GET também com `sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-3.1` e após toda a instalação é exibido:

> Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
> Construindo árvore de dependências
> Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
> **E: Impossível encontrar o pacote dotnet-sdk-3.1**
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-3.1'
> E: Não foi possível encontrar o pacote através da expressão regular 'dotnet-sdk-3.1'

Pensei que o problema pudesse ser variável de ambiente, porém, pesquisando, não localizei nada a respeito.

Segui tutoriais voltados para o Ubuntu, por ser o Mint um SO que, como ele também é baseado no Debian. Não encontrei nada específico para instalar neste sistema operacional.

Comment: Já tentou seguir [esse tutorial da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004-) ?

Answer (score -1):

Cara no meu tava dando o mesmo problema, ai eu fui ver os erros e correções que tinham ali no próprio sie da microsoft e fui testando, ate que eu consegui com esse comando:

sudo dpkg --purge packages-microsoft-prod && sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update